# How to check boolean condition in a VM (velocity) file

Tags: java, boolean, velocity

I have a pojo class, named as client.java. it has a field as

private boolean yieldStressColumns;

The setter and getters are :

```
public void setExcelAttachFlag(boolean excelAttachFlag) {
    this.excelAttachFlag = excelAttachFlag;
}

public boolean isYieldStressColumns() {
    return yieldStressColumns;
```

Now i have to display something based on condition. if the yieldStressColumns is "true", then only i will see a particular view. can you tell me how to do boolean check in vm (velocity) file. I am doing like this which shows red mark on vm file :-

```
#if (${client.isYieldStressColumns() = true})

<<<<< some code -->>>>      

#end
```

Comment: Actually you assign the value true. Comparison is `==` but you can leave the `= true` part away completely.

Answer (score 4):

```
#if (${client.yieldStressColumns})

<<<<< some code -->>>>      

#end
```

Comment: is this is correct     #if (${client.yieldStressColumns})     or                      #if (${client.isyieldStressColumns})

Comment: And the curly braces are not necessary here.

Comment: And if you want to negate a boolean then put the `!` before the `$` e.g.: `#if (!$client.yieldStressColumns)`